# Docebo - Setting up OAuth JWT Bearer grant type - Public key is invalid

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token

I tried to set up an OAuth 2.0 client on [API Credentials page](https://yourtenant.docebosaas.com/legacy/lms/index.php%3Fr%3DApiApp/ApiApp/settings) in Docebo with JWT Bearer grant type and upload a Public Key that is used to verify the signature of incoming assertion (JWT Bearer token). Docebo shows an error that Public Key is invalid (see an image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McigW.png) below).

I tried the following certificate file formats with public keys. Docebo doesn't  accept them:

1. Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)
2. DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER)

Instructions from [Docebo - APIs Authentication](https://www.docebo.com/knowledge-base/authentication-api-ssp-app-grant-types/) do not specify the file format too.

In which format Docebo accepts a Public Key for JWT Bearer grant type?

[Image of "Public Key is invalid error message" in Docebo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McigW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docebo accepts public keys in PEM format (Base-64 encoded public key of X.509 certificate):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDMYfnvWtC8Id5bPKae5yXSxQTt
+Zpul6AnnZWfIdasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfasdfLKJKGCsRqMFDkrbeUjRrx8iL91
4/srnyf6sh9c8Zk04xEOpK1ypvBz+Ks4uZObtjnnitf0NBGdjMKxveTq+VE7BWUI
yQjtQ8mbDOsiLLvh7wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

To get a public key of a base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER) use the following command:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -in certificate.cer -noout 1>PublicKey.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

For docebo, which accepts .PEM format for public key. Here is the link which provides more info. on how to generate the PEM formatted public key using openssl command i.e. https://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php