# How do I convert a SSH2 PUBLIC KEY (rsa-key file) to PEM? (Base-64 encoded public key of X.509 certificate)

Tags: putty, public-key-encryption, private-key, pem

I have a private/public key that was generated by Putty in the following format:

```
SSH2 PUBLIC KEY rsa-key
```

However, I am trying to get it to work with [Docebo API using the JWT Grant Type](https://www.docebo.com/knowledge-base/authentication-api-ssp-app-grant-types/#post-simple-toc-heading-6), which requires a different format (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334239/docebo-setting-up-oauth-jwt-bearer-grant-type-public-key-is-invalid)).

How would I convert my key(s) to work with that format?  Is there a way within Putty?

Comment: Are you sure you were supposed to use PuTTY? It seems that Docebo uses certificates. PuTTY generates simple keypairs. A certificate is much more complicated thing than a key pair.

Comment: It's possible that I cannot use Putty.  What is the correct way to do it?  I'm not super familiar with the process. Does it involve Openssl?  What are the commands needed?

Comment: OpenSSL can create certificates indeed. But I cannot help any further, as I'm not familiar with Docebo.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the steps to take to get the proper format of key using OpenSSL:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out publickey.cer 
openssl x509 -in publickey.cer -out publickey.pem
```